# In Java, how to specify options for reading a csv?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I attempt to use options with the read() method and then call csv(), it does not seem to apply my options. For example:

```
session.read().option("sep", delim).option("header", true).csv
```

Do options with read() only work when you use load() like this:

```
session.read().format("csv").option("header", false).option("sep", delim).load
```

or should it work both ways? Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `delim`?

Comment: The value of delim is "|"

Comment: @Reema `spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", "|").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("pipe.csv")` this works fine!

Comment: What does inferSchema do?